# Limit and sort, from what word must start next result

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

My problem is i use query which must return N values when I call it first, then
next N values etc. Also I have some types of sort like sort by date, sort by word name etc., asc and desc variants. Where I use sort by date I can use something like id>N (in my code a>3) i.e. first id is be 4, last id is 9 then in next query first will be 10 and last 15 etc. but what to do if I need to sort by word name, how I can determine from what word to start?

```
  select distinct s.a,w._word
  from (
        select a from edges 
        where a in 
        (
            select distinct w._id
            from edges as e 
            inner join words as w
            on w._id=e.a
            where w.lang_id=2
        ) and b in
        (
            select distinct w._id
            from edges as e 
            inner join words as w
            on w._id=e.b
            where w.lang_id=1
        )
        union
        select b from edges 

        where b in 
        (
            select distinct w._id
            from edges as e 
            inner join words as w
            on w._id=e.b
            where w.lang_id=2
        ) and a in
        (
            select distinct w._id
            from edges as e 
            inner join words as w
            on w._id=e.a
            where w.lang_id=1
        )
) as s
inner join words as w
on s.a=w._id 
inner join groups_set as gs
on w._id=gs.word_id
 where gs.group_id in (1,2,3) or w._word like '%d%' and a>3
order by w._word desc limit 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I getting the question wrong? `LIMIT` can be used with an offset.

Either like

```
... LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5
```

or

```
... LIMIT 5, 5
```

You don't work the offset out in the query, you just increase it in your application.

And with this you can also `ORDER BY` whatever you want.